# Is there a way to pass a string variable to a for loop in Java?

Tags: java

My requirement is to delete data from a database, but the strings I need to pass to the `DELETE` query are dynamically generated, so I have to first collect the data and then use it in a `for` loop that would send the `DELETE` query multiple times.

My steps so far:

First, I filtered a list so as to collect a list of required elements into a variable. I got the expected output:

```
List<String> newFilter = allProductNames.stream().filter(field -> field.startsWith("sample", 1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(newFilter)
```

Output:

```
"sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4"
```

Now, I want to use each of the elements to send a query to a Neo4j database, using the query - `DROP DATABASE <database_name> wait;` where `<database_name>` would be replaced by each of my collected elements. So the queries will look like this:

```
DROP DATABASE sample1 wait;
DROP DATABASE sample2 wait;
DROP DATABASE sample3 wait;
DROP DATABASE sample4 wait;
DROP DATABASE sample5 wait;
```

What comes straight to my mind is that a `for` loop can help me to send the query repeatedly by passing `sample1` in the first query, `sample2` in the second query...and so on, but my dilemma is that I am lost on how to achieve this.

I tried something like this, but it wont work:

```
List<String> newFilter = allProductNames.stream().filter(field -> field.startsWith("sample", 1)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    int filterSize = newFilter.size();

    int i = 0;
    String dropDatabase = "DROP DATABASE " + i + " wait;"; //i want to pass the element as a variable here

    for (; i < filterSize ; i++) {

      basePage.queryInputField.sendKeys(dropDatabase);
    }
```

What I was trying to do in the loop is to pass make `i = sample1` in the first run, `i = sample2` in the second run and so on, but `i` is an `int` and I believe only an `int` can be passed into a condition as far as my little Java knowledge.

How can I pass the `String` `sample1` to the loop in the first run to achieve this - `DROP DATABASE sample1 wait;` and pass the other elements in subsequent runs? I am open to any other approach than can help me achieve this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a ListIterator? Much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are not updating the dropDatabase String at any moment in the loop.

You have two options, use a for each or a for i updating the string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < filterSize; i++) {
    basePage.queryInputField.sendKeys("DROP DATABASE " + newFilter.get(i) + " wait;");
}


for (String database : newFilter) {
    basePage.queryInputField.sendKeys("DROP DATABASE " + database + " wait;");
}
```

Or if you want the query string apart you could also use a format like this:

```
String format = "DROP DATABASE %s wait;";
for (String database : newFilter) {
    basePage.queryInputField.sendKeys(String.format(format, database));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (String dbName : newFilter) {
    String dropDatabase = "DROP DATABASE " + dbName + " wait;";
    basePage.queryInputField.sendKeys(dropDatabase);
}
```